# Drupal views to display content updated today

Tags: views

For a drupal view, I want a filter such that in the block I can see Articles (created with a taxonomy term) either

Created/Posted today
Updated today (might be created earlier)
This is what I've done. I've added filters to the view:

Content: Has taxonomy term (= something)
Content: Published (Yes)
And contextual filters:

Content: Created day [With default value to be Current Date]
Content: Updated day [With default value to be Current Date]
With these settings I'm achieving my purpose of getting the posts which were created today, but the posts which were created earlier and updated today are not being picked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the filters all you should need is:

Content: Updated day [With default value to be Current Date]

Because you have the created date filter you are currently only getting nodes created today.

Comment: Hi rooby. I did as u said, and it works! Thanks :)